# What is the difference of using this.name or name in this case?

Tags: java

```
package holinheritation2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inheritation2 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Animal wolf = new Animal();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.next();
        wolf.setName(name);

        if (wolf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Kobe")) {
            System.out.println("You are a wolf called Kobe!");
        }
    }

}

package holinheritation2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;  
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

`enter code here`}
```

What is the purpose of writing `this.name = name` and is there any difference if I return "name" instead of "this.name" on the getName method? I think I understand `this.name = name` however clarification is appreciated.

Comment: this.name => the instance variable, name => the local variable you accept as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` refers to the local variable name defined within the method. The `this.name` refers to the variable set in the class.

This is used in order the compiler to be able to distinguish variables set with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of writing "this.name = name"

I assume you mean in `setName`. In `setName`, `this.name` is your instance variable ("field"), and `name` is the parameter `setName` accepts. So `this.name = name` sets the instance field's value using the parameter's value.

> is there any difference if I return "name" instead of "this.name" on the getName method?

No, because there isn't any `name` parameter or local variable in scope in `getName`, so the Java compiler knows you mean the `name` instance variable. (Always including `this` even when it's not needed, or not using it when it's not needed, is a style choice.)

Answer (score 0):

This is done when there is shadowing, You have `name` variable declared twice, one within method as parameter or local variable, other as member of class, within the method variable member is shadowed by parameter variable `name`, so to access it you have to specify `this.name` which refers to the member variable `name`.

Hence within the method `name` variable refers to the parameter where as `this.name` refers to the member variable `name`.
so shadowing is resolved.

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the local variable has the same name as the instance variable, then then the local variable will hide the instance variable and you have to use "this" keyword in order to access the hidden instance variable.